# How can I sort data in text file by number and name with python?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a text file with ~500 lines of data, formatted like this:

compound_name score = number

ex: ethanol score = -4.444

Each score is on a different line. I want to sort by ascending/ descending order, and then determine the order of compound_names. How can I do this with python/ python packages?

Comment: Could you post the code you attempted and what's the issues you're having?

Comment: Read the file line by line. Split each line at the `=`. Convert the stringified number to a real number. Add this data (a tuple of name and number) to a list. Sort the list according to the number. Ready. - At the moment your question is far to broad.

Comment: In addition to @Matthias advice - look at `configparser` module that will make easier to read and process the file.

Comment: Oh yes, `configparser` might be a good idea. I used it only once, so that didn't come to mind.

Comment: @Matthias, how would I go about splitting the lines and adding to a list? I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: You should take your time. Read the tutorial and understand the basics first. For splitting you can use the strings [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method. For appending something to a list you can use the lists [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=append#lists) method.